# How can I synchronize multiple socket.io clients accessing a single deque/set/list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, synchronization, python-socketio

I am subscribing to multiple socket.io servers at the same time, all incoming entries get checked whether they have been already processed/received by another websocket client. The servers provide me with data that should be added into a single list, the order of the list is important, as it represents an orderbook from an exchange. An entry should not be added twice.
With my current solution I am experiencing race conditions, as far as I know socket.io is using asyncio, a simple threading.Lock won't help.

```
sio = socketio.Client()
sio1 = socketio.Client()
locker = threading.Lock()
added_Orders = collections.deque(maxlen=40)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connection established')

@sio1.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connection1 established')

@sio.on('add_order', namespace="/market")
def add_order(data):
    with locker:
        if data in added_Orders:
            return
        else:
            added_Orders.append(data)
    webRecv.process_add(data)

@sio1.on('add_order', namespace="/market")
def add_order1(data):
    with locker:
        if data in added_Orders:
            return
        else:
            added_Orders.append(data)
    webRecv.process_add(data)
```

Comment: You need to explain better what you mean by "socket.io is using asyncio". The code that you posted does not appear to be using asyncio, so where is asyncio used?

Comment: @Miguel Thanks for your response! I am not using asyncio in my code, however I was assuming that socketio uses asyncio, since the 'with locker' intended blocks do not lead to the desired behaviour. Sometimes the code is processing duplicate data.

Comment: The `socketio.Client` class does not use asyncio, it uses standard multithreaded APIs in Python from the `threading` package. How complex is your `data` elements? If they are dicts, they'll have to be 100% identical to be detected as duplicates. I think a better strategy in that case would be for you to check some sort of identifier that is a simpler value and not a dict.

Comment: @Miguel thank you so much, what a simple solution! Indeed they are dicts, apperently there is a value different to the data received by the other clients. Extracting the id and comparing it works!